# Getting the error "Debug assertion failed error" all of a sudden without any code change been done. (In C++ code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, assertions

My VC++ code was working (executing) perfectly alright & now all of a sudden I don't understand why am I getting the error "Debug assertion failed".

```
file:f\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\fclose.c.
```

I am using VS2008 on WIn7 64bit OS.

What might be the reason that a code which was working fine started breaking in this manner all of a sudden without any code changes?

Can anyone kindly help me in getting rid of this error?

I saw in the call stack that the code before this is in the file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src\crt0dat.c
```

```
while ( pfbegin < pfend )              
    {                
        /*             
         * if current table entry is non-NULL, call thru it.               
         */                      
        if ( *pfbegin != NULL )                  
            (**pfbegin)();              
        ++pfbegin;                       
    }
```

And yes, `fclose()` is receiving a null file pointer. I seriously don't understand why is this getting wrong file pointer value, all of a sudden without me doing any change to the code or to the environment.

Comment: Can you please post any relevant code snippet (code lines before assertion fails)?

Comment: Guess: the file open by the corresponding `fopen()` failed resulting in a null pointer being passed to `fclose()`?

Comment: Yes I have edited the necessary code in my question. :)

Comment: What types are `pfbegin` and `pfend`? Declaration?

Comment: And yes, it's pretty common that some bugs take a long time before they show any effect. Testing can never cover all possible input combinations and circumstances.

Comment: This loop is for static / global variables, and it is written by Microsoft. Do you have such variables in your code?Maybe you have rearanged them?

Comment: No sir I havent manipulated even a bit of my code and I am suddenly getting this error. DOn't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the code which calls `fclose()`?
I may guess that `fopen()` failed to open the file returning NULL, e.g. because file doesn't exist. You didn't check for this error and passed NULL handle to `fclose()`.

Comment: I observe in the call stack that the caller si not mentione dproperly. It again is some standard Microsoft given file and not my code. AND 1 STRANGE THING I OBSERVED IS THAT EVEN IF I PRESS F10 FOR LINE BY LINE DEBUGGING. iTS DIRECTLY TROWING THIS "DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ERROR". SO NOT ABLE TO MAKE OUT ANYTHING PROPERLY. Very strange behavior !!

Comment: If you keep reading down the callstack you must reach your own code at some time, or you have completely smashed the stack somehow.

Comment: If I keep going down in the call stack I just find some Dlls for which there is no code again microsoft dlls. Can You plz let  me know what did you mean by "Smashed the stack completely?? Is my VS set up corrupt ? Will it work if I reinstall my VS2008 ?

Comment: Might it be that you got buffer overrun when you're reading the file? Could you please pay the attention to `fread` calls to make sure that the size of memory allocated for `buffer` is enough for the data you read, that is isn't less than `size*count`?